# disable speech Option in web channels and direct line in microsoft bot framework v3 and v4 Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, speech-recognition

I have a problem. I was referring through this [link](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/26/speech-to-text/)! 
and found out that the speech option is automatically enabled in web chats and direct line applications. Is their a way i can disable speech option in my channels?
I went through the link above, but it doesnot tell anything about disabling speech in channels.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using v3 or v4 of WebChat? By default, speech is disabled in v4.